# hibernate order by nested entity field with possible null values

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I've stumbled upon a problem with Hibernate. I've 2 entities - let's say A and B like so (Entity/Table annotations ommited):

```
class A {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;
}

class B {
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Now, I'm trying to query all **A** entities and ordering them by **name** field of **B**'s entity like so:

```
SELECT q FROM A AS q ORDER BY q.b.name asc nulls last
```

The problem is, there are rows in **A**'s table having null foreign-key (**b is null**) - in result the aforementioned query returns **only** rows that don't contain null in **b** field, and I'd like to have them all.

I guess hibernate joins the table without using LEFT JOIN (OUTER JOIN?) resulting in null values being skipped.

Is there any way to change this behaviour? It would be great, if I could solve it by using annotations in entity classes, because the query-generating mechanism is pretty locked up.

Comment: What do you mean by *the query-generating mechanism is pretty locked up*?

Comment: It's very generic, and here I got the special case which happens in 0.001% of all queries ever made.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CriteriaBuilder and set alias on entityRoot

```
Root<A> entityRoot = criteriaQuery.from(A);
entityRoot.join("b", JoinType.LEFT).alias("b");
criteriaQuery.select(entityRoot)
                .orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(entityRoot.get("b").get("name"))
```

;

Answer (score 0):

you can use criteria query for this but you will have to create session while using that, it is simpler to access database using criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class)

//create alias of your other class to provide ordering according to foriegn key

criteria.createAlias("foreignkey","keyin table A(eg..b)");
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(b.name));
List list = criteria.getlist();
```

hope this helps

Comment: I cannot use any other mechanism - we're creating JPQL queries as Strings, because we have pretty big frontend query-generating mechanism.